# Why do I get a frequency of letters and not words?

Tags: python, split, frequency

```
text = input('Enter a line of text. (You might consider coping and pasting text'): 
text = text.lower()

words=text.split()
words=sorted(words)
wordsdict={}

for words in text:
    wordsdict.setdefault(words,0)
    wordsdict[words] = wordsdict[words]+1

print(wordsdict)
```

Comment: look closely at how you are using text.split().   Think about where a "word" should be split, and whether your use of text.split() will achieve that.

Comment: you should replace ```for words in text```with ```for word in words```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have `words = text.split()`, but you never iterate through `words` in your code. You *do* have `for words in text:`, where the `words` is *not* what you defined before, it is a new variable in each iteration.

So `for words in text:` is actually iterating through each character in `text`, where `text` is a string.

Here is the corrected version:

```
text = input('Enter a line of text. (You might consider coping and pasting text): ')
text = text.lower()

words=text.split()
words=sorted(words)

wordsdict={}

for word in words:
    wordsdict.setdefault(word,0)
    wordsdict[word] = wordsdict[word]+1

print(wordsdict)
```

Comment: and python has a container for that as well: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @SedyVlk I'm aware, but I'm focusing on correcting the logic of the current code.